# How to format inside a for loop?

Tags: python

Greetings everyone here is my code.

```
empList="""201911007,James,Butt,Accounting,365;
201203008,Josephine,Darakjy,Marketing,4000"""

all_data = []
for row in map(str.strip, empList.split(";")):
    if row == "":
        continue
    id, fname, lname, dept, rate = row.split(",")
    all_data.append((int(id), fname, lname, dept, rate))
    
def display():
    for id, fname, lname, dept, rate in all_data:
        print(f"""Employee ID: {id}
First name: {fname}
Last name: {lname}
Department: {dept}
Rate per Day: {rate}\n""")
display()
```

I basically need to change

```
Rate per Day: 400
```

to

```
Rate per Day: 400.00
```

How do I do it? I tried doing  `float(rate)` but it only showed `400.0`

Comment: Rate per Day: {rate:.0} see https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/

Comment: try:- `all_data.append((int(id), fname, lname, dept,"{:.2f}".format(int(rate))))`

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to make the value a float

   ```
   all_data.append((int(id), fname, lname, dept, float(rate)))
   ```
2. Specify to format with 2 digits after comma

   ```
   Rate per Day: {rate:.2f}\n
   ```